# Images and <div> pulled from Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I view the source code for a site such as www.dribble.com I see that each image has it's own `<div>`, however when I pull images from my rails models with code such as:

```
<div class="article">
 <% @articles.in_groups_of(5, false).each do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
   <% group.each do |article| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">
       <%= link_to image_tag(article.artwork.thumb), ?? %>
       <%= sanitize(article.title) %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @articles %>
```

the images come as a single `<div>`. Instagram source code also shows that a user's 9 photos in their home page is single `<div>` and Instagram and their photo layout looks very similar to images plucked from a Rails model.

Does this mean that it is not possible to pull images from a Rails model and make them fancy/responsive the way you see on www.dribble.com ?

Also, do the other languages that allow you to make your photos responsive/fancy also provide you with the ability to pull images from models or does a site like www.dribble.com have to manually code each `<div>`/image? I ask because in every beginner's tutorial I see for java/html they are hand writing imgs into the code, I haven't seen any examples that are pulling images from models/databases the way they do in the Rails tutorials.

As a bonus, in the above code I am trying to figure out two things:

1. `rb.6` how to create a link to the id of the article, "example.com/article/1"
2. `rb.6` how to create a link to the url attached in the :title column. The title is entered into my form under the title column as `<a href="http://cnn.com">Foo Bar</a>` and then sanitized in `rb.7` to "Foo Bar".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused with the role of `Rails` / `CSS`.

---

We use [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for our images; it doesn't matter whether you're using it or [`Carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) - the pattern is the same.

Images are saved on a hard drive (either locally on web server, or externally on `S3` etc), `Paperclip` / `Carrierwave` then store references to the images in your db. When you call the image through Rails, you're only pulling the `image.jpg` data through the db & ultimately the hdd.

The stylization of the image is entirely up to you:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "article" do %>
  <% @articles.in_groups_of(5, false).each do |group| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, class:"row do %">
      <% group.each do |article| %>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <%= link_to image_tag(article.artwork.thumb), article %>
          <%= sanitize(article.title) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Since the above looks messy, you may wish to adopt [`haml`](https://github.com/haml/haml):

```
.class
  - @articles.in_groups_of(5, false).each do |group|
    .row
      - group.each do |article|
        .col-md-2
          = link_to image_tag(article.artwork.thumb), article 
          = sanitize article.title
```

---

> how to create a link to the `id` of the article

You should read up about [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) - you just have to pass the "output" followed by the URL. As Rails uses a [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) structure, you'll be able to pass the `article` object directly:

```
link_to "Text", article                #-> <a href="example.com/articles/[[id]]">Text</a>
link_to "Text", articles_path(article) #-> <a href="example.com/articles/[[id]]">Text</a>
```

This considers you have the following set up in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles
```

--

> how to create a link to the url attached in the :title column

Not sure what you're asking; if you want to pass a `block` to your `link_to`, you could use:

```
= link_to article do
  = image_tag article.artwork.thumb
  = sanitize article.title
```

... which will yield:

```
<a href="http://example.com/articles/[[id]]">
  <img src="..." />
  Title
</a>
```

---

> make them fancy/responsive

Entirely a `CSS` issue.